# What happens if the width $a$ of the potential well gets large or goes to infinity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

What happens to the wavefunction if for a 1D infinite potential well of certain width $a$, we let $a$ go-to infinity?

I think then is just a free particle and therefore it can be described with a plane wave.